# Merge rows based on two different IDs

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to sort a table according to two different columns.

This is what I have:

```
| EAN | album_id | photo     |
|-----|----------|-----------|
| 111 | 123      | 64.jpg    |
| 111 | 123      | 65.jpg    |
| 222 | 123      | 64.jpg    |
| 222 | 123      | 65.jpg    |
```

This is the desired result:

```
| EAN | album_id | photo          | primary |
|-----|----------|----------------|---------|
| 111 | 123      | 64.jpg, 65.jpg | 1       |
| 222 | 123      | 64.jpg, 65.jpg | 0       |
```

This is the raw code I'm working with (I change it for my specific need), so far it only handles the album_id and photo sorting but not the EAN or primary columns:

```
Sub merge()
Dim LR As Long, Delim As String

'Allow user to set the Delimiter
    Delim = Application.InputBox("Merge column B values with what delimiter?", "Delimiter", "|", Type:=2)
    If Delim = "False" Then Exit Sub
    If Delim = "" Then
        If MsgBox("You chose a blank delimiter, this will merge column B value into a single continuous string. Proceed?", _
            vbYesNo, "Merge with no delimiter") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If

'Sort data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Concatenate column B values so last matching row in each group has all values
    With Range("E2:E" & LR)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1=R[-1]C1, R[-1]C & " & """" & Delim & """" & " & RC2, RC2)"
        .Value = .Value
        .Copy Range("B2")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1=R[1]C1, """", 1)"
        Range("E:E").AutoFilter 1, "<>1"
        .EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        .EntireColumn.Clear
    End With
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Columns.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can I change the code (in part or completely) to achieve the end result I'm looking for?

Thank you very much for any help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to be deleting rows so sort first then work from the bottom up.

```
dim i as long, delim as string

delim = ", "

with worksheets("sheet1")
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        .cells.sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Key2:=.Columns(2), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlyes
        for i = .rows.count -1  to 2 step -1
            if .cells(i, "A").value = .cells(i+1, "A").value and _
               .cells(i, "B").value = .cells(i+1, "B").value then
                .cells(i, "C").value = .cells(i, "C").value & delim & .cells(i+1, "C").value
                .cells(i+1, "A").entirerow.delete
                .cells(i, "D").value = abs(iserror(application.match(.cells(i, "B").value, .range(.cells(1, "B"),.cells(i-1, "B")), 0)))
            end if
        next i
    end with
end with
```

[image]

Comment: what is the reason you are getting the absolute value for the cells in column D?

Comment: I'm using IsError with Match to determine if there are any values in column B above the current row. IsError returns boolean. In vba, false is zero and true is -1. Abs changes true to 1 for column D.

Comment: Given the op's limited explanation of column D, it was the best logic I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, +1

Comment: Thank you this does the job

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Dictionary` object and `TextToColumns` method of `Range` object

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim key As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Item(cell.Value & "|" & cell.Offset(, 1).Value) = .Item(cell.Value & "|" & cell.Offset(, 1).Value) & cell.Offset(, 2).Value & " "
        Next

        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Clear
        For Each key In .Keys
            Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = key
            Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Join(Split(Trim(.Item(key)), " "), ",")
        Next
        Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns Range("A2"), xlDelimited, , , , , , , True, "|"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Charles, any feedback?